# Export from AppEngine database to the local development database?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to export the data on my AppEngine database to the development server (for testing purposes etc.) ?

Answer (score 10):

Yes! Check out Google's ["Uploading and Downloading Data"](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Loading_Data_Into_the_Development_Server)

> If you'd like to test how your data
>   works with the app before uploading
>   it, you can load it into the
>   development server. Use the --url
>   option to point the tool at the
>   development server URL. For example:

```
 appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=album_loader.py --filename=album_data.csv --kind=Album --url=http://localhost:8080/remote_api <app-directory>
```

The [subsection on uploading and downloading all data](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data) is also worth looking at.

Comment: I don't think that's what he was asking, I think he was asking for a way to get the data *off* of Google's servers and onto his local machine.

Comment: The way it works is that you first download all the data from app engine, and then you "upload" it into your development server.

Comment: Is that possible for java GAE?

Answer (score 2):

**[Not yet it seems](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=776)**

Of course you can go pulling the data yourself, one batch at a time...

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can download all data from google app engine and can upload to datastore but sometimes uploading data to local development server is painfull because of errors. App Engine SDK versioning diffrences occurs this like problems. For example i developed an app 1 year ago. Today, i want update it. I downloaded all data from Google App Engine real servers. But i can't upload its to local development server. You know, we using EntityLoader class for this operation. Entity Class importing db module, but SDK throws, "no module named by db".

I suggest for App Engine lovers that; save your first test data for future. Don't think that i will download all datum for testing future. Save your own test data with Sqlite support. And save your deveopment enviromenment version for future. SDK Version updating sometimes causing painfully times for developers