# Sqlite db scheme to Django models

Tags: google-app-engine, sqlite, database-backups

I am trying to get my local sqlite db up and running on GAE. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370433/how-can-i-port-my-sqlite-database-up-to-gae), there is no way for me to get my local db up there directly. That's why I would like to do something like this:

1. I get the sqlite db up and running on my dev server with this: http://code.google.com/p/gae-sqlite/
2. Locally, I translate the db scheme into django model and migrate the db into GAE db.
3. I use [google's way](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Loading_Data_Into_the_Development_Server) to get my data up to GAE.

So here comes my question. Is there any project that is able to directly translate sqlite db scheme into django model directly?

If not, I guess I will have to write up a code gen.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gae-sqlite (now superceded by built-in sqlite support) is designed to run the development appserver backend on sqlite for speed and reduced memory consumption. It doesn't let you import or use your own sqlite schema in App Engine.

You need to dump your data to CSV files, and use the App Engine bulkloader (which you linked to) to bulkload them into the dev_appserver and production environments. Alternately, it is possible to bulkload direct from the sqlite database, but that's a lot more involved, and probably not worth the effort.