# How to harmonize local dev environment with production?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2, webapp2, wtforms

My local environment and my production environment are not compatible anymore. The problem is that I'm using IDs and keys for an entity, region, where some of those keys are hardcoded and I can't get it out what has been hardcoded yet.

```
class City(db.Model):
  region = db.ReferenceProperty()
  name = db.StringProperty()

class Region(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  countrycode = db.StringProperty()
  vieworder = db.IntegerProperty()
  areacode = db.IntegerProperty()
  areacodes = db.ListProperty(int)
```

Many regions and cities were populated in the production environment using the above model which appears to work. But I've been forced to hardcode these generated IDs on production when making inserts i.e.

```
  <select onchange="cities(this);document.getElementById('area').display='';" name="region" id="region">
                                <option value="">«{% trans %}Choose region{% endtrans %}»</option>
                                <option value="4703187">

                     Andaman &amp; Nicobar Islands
                </option>
<option value="4694186">

                     Andhra Pradesh
                </option>
<option value="4699188">

                     Arunachal Pradesh
                </option>
<option value="4692186">

                     Assam
                </option>
<option value="4702186">

                     Bihar
                </option>
<option value="4698185">

                     Chandigarh
                </option>
<option value="4676188">

                     Chhattisgarh
                </option>
<option value="4691190">

                     Dadra &amp; Nagar Haveli
                </option>
<option value="4704183">

                     Daman &amp; Diu
                </option>
<option value="4699183">

                     Delhi
                </option>
<option value="4702187">

                     Goa
                </option>
<option value="4691189">

                     Gujarat
                </option>
<option value="4700186">

                     Haryana
                </option>
<option value="4703185">

                     Himachal Pradesh
                </option>
<option value="4694187">

                     Jammu &amp; Kashmir
                </option>
<option value="4699189">

                     Jharkhand
                </option>
<option value="4701185">

                     Karnataka
                </option>
<option value="4695189">

                     Kerala
                </option>
<option value="4700189">

                     Lakshadweep
                </option>
<option value="4697186">

                     Madhya Pradesh
                </option>
<option value="4694184">

                     Maharashtra
                </option>
<option value="4700187">

                     Manipur
                </option>
<option value="4703186">

                     Meghalaya
                </option>
<option value="4698184">

                     Mizoram
                </option>
<option value="4692187">

                     Nagaland
                </option>
<option value="4696185">

                     Orissa
                </option>
<option value="4676189">

                     Pondicherry
                </option>
<option value="4693185">

                     Punjab
                </option>
<option value="4701186">

                     Rajasthan
                </option>
<option value="4701187">

                     Sikkim
                </option>
<option value="4701188">

                     Tamil Nadu
                </option>
<option value="4697187">

                     Tripura
                </option>
<option value="4699190">

                     Uttaranchal
                </option>
<option value="4692188">

                     Uttar Pradesh
                </option>
<option value="4700188">

                     West Bengal
                </option>

                        </select>
```

I use WTForms and some special enhancements so it's going to be tricky to get all the hardcoded IDs out of the system, is there anthing else smart that I can do to make m local envirnment work again, is it possible to import the regions and cities from production to local so that they have the same IDs? If yes, how can it be done? I also have this problem for categories whose IDs are hardcoded in a manner similar to above.

Comment: Maybe you could use the actual names of the regions as their keys as they are unique and limited in length. That way at least no mapping would be needed. (I am not sure that city names are unique but maybe they are in a single region so if you use the region as parent they could also have their names as their IDs.)

Comment: @gaborlenard I tried using names as keys but it fails since I have thousands of cities and some of them have same names and many cities are also "named" "Other city" since I got that option when doing a search. But these IDs are only in 2 or 3 places so I think I can make them soft and variables, like moving settings variable from properties file to datastore for a more flexible application that I can distribute with an empty datastore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have hardcoded values, then by definition, they're going to be written down somewhere, so why can't you use the same list of values on both test and production servers?  Or by hardcoded, do you mean, stored in a database?

I think your question might really be, how can you export the datastore from the production datastore, and load it into your local test server, in which case, this related StackOverflow question should help : [Export from AppEngine database to the local development database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837028/export-from-appengine-database-to-the-local-development-database)

Comment: If you don't have too many (say <10000) copying using remote api and a little bit of python pretty easy

Comment: Yes, stored in database. I populated my regions and cities and then there were keys and IDs generated on production which I hardcoded into the pages to save development time. I suppose it can be done without hardcoding the values in the presentation layer, then I could keep a separate geogrphy local than on production. Another solution could be to import the region and city entities from production to local, I think that would be all I need.